# Finding the determinant of a 4x4 matrix quickly

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I know that I can find the determinant by working my way from 4x4 to 3x3 to 2x2 determinant. However that is long.

Which other method can I use?

\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 & 6 \\
2 & 5 & 3 & 0 \\
1 & 6 & 0 &-2 \\
0 &-2 & 5 & -1
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Hints: Use $0$'s to cut down on the work.  Also, you can add a multiple of one row to another row without changing the determinant.  For example, here, you could start with $-2R_3+R_1\rightarrow R_1$ and $-2R_3+R_2\rightarrow R_2$ to introduce more zeros in the first column.  In general, it takes some work to compute a determinant (practice to speed up the calculation)

Comment: You could start by decomposing along column 3 since this already has 2 zeros-less work to do. Alternatively, you could just use elementary row operations as suggested in the above comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substract twice the third row both from the second and the first rows to get:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&-11&0&10\\0&-7&3&4\\1&6&0&-2\\0&-2&5&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Develop by the first column and get:

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}-11&0&10\\-7&3&4\\-2&5&-1\end{pmatrix}=33+0-350+220-0+60=-37$$

Comment: why does this work?

Comment: @WiccanKarnak Basic properties of general multilinear functions: as long as you add **any** scalar multiple of a row/column to a row/column, the determinant doesn't change. The development by row/column is another thing but also based on the same basic properties.